# Divide two queries to get pass rate of each semester

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query for a table where I am looking to determine what is the pass rate for a semester.

The first query (QUERY 1) will give me the number of students passed in a semester and the second query (QUERY 2) will give me the total number of students in a semester for a particular subject with code = 4897.

I need to perform the calculation (QUERY 1/QUERY 2) and display the results by semesters code.

QUERY 1:

```
 select count(c.student) as q1, s.semester
 from course_enrolments c join courses s on c.course = s.id
 where s.subject = 4897 and mark >= 50
 group by s.semester;
```

QUERY 2:

```
 select count(c.student) as q2, s.semester
 from course_enrolments c join courses s on c.course = s.id
 where s.subject = 4897
 group by s.semester;
```

> Then q1/q2 =

The result should be like this:

```
semester | pass_rate | 
------+--------------+
    03   |      1.00 |         
    04   |      1.00 |        
    05   |      1.00 |         
    06   |      1.00 |        
    07   |      1.00 |         
    08   |      0.81 |    
    09   |      0.89 |
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select s.semester,
       count(*) as num_students,
       sum(case when mark >= 50 then 1 else 0 end) as passes,
       avg(case when mark >= 50 then 1.0 else 0 end) as pass_rate,
from course_enrolments c join
     courses s
     on c.course = s.id
where s.subject = 4897 and mark >= 50
group by s.semester;
```

Comment: PERFECT NOW! THANKS!